# Spark sliding window performance

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've setup a pipeline for incoming events from a stream in Apache Kafka.

Spark connects to Kafka, get the stream from a topic and process some "simple" aggregation tasks.

As I'm trying to build a service that should have a low latency refresh (below 1 second) I've built a simple Spark streaming app in Scala.

```
val windowing = events.window(Seconds(30), Seconds(1))

val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Main Processor")
      .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

// Go into RDD of DStream
windowing.foreachRDD(rdd => {
    // Convert RDD of JSON into DataFrame
    val df = spark.read.json(rdd)      

    // Process only if received DataFrame is not empty
    if (!df.head(1).isEmpty) {

    // Create a view for Spark SQL
    val rdf = df.select("user_id", "page_url")

    rdf.createOrReplaceTempView("currentView")

    val countDF = spark.sql("select count(distinct user_id) as sessions from currentView")

    countDF.show()
}
```

It works as expected. My concerns are about performance at this point. Spark is running on a 4 CPUs Ubuntu server for testing purpose.

The CPU usage is about 35% all the time. I'm wondering if the incomming data from the stream have let's say 500 msg/s how would the CPU usage will evolve? Will it grow exp. or in a linear way?

If you can share your experience with Apache Spark in that kind of situation I'd appreciate it.

Last open question is if I set the sliding window interval to 500ms (as I'd like) will this blow up? I mean, it seems that Spark streaming features are fresh and the batch processing architecture may be a limitation in really real time data processing, isn't it?